# How to echo the cURL result in PHP?

Tags: php, json, curl

Here is a URL→ https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=snoopy&rsz=1

and this is my php code

```
<?php
    $url = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?"."v=1.0&q=snoopy";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $body = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $json = json_decode($body);
?>
```

I wanna echo all of the image urls from its result 
(For example: http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20110331075248/peanuts/images/6/62/Snoopy.gif )

But I have no idea how to echo them.
Hope someone could help me, thanks!

Comment: if the link comes as a response then just echo `$body` :-?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe like this:

```
<?php
    $url = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?" .
   "v=1.0&q=barack%20obama&userip=INSERT-USER-IP";

   // sendRequest
   // note how referer is set manually
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://example.com');
   $body = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);

   // now, process the JSON string
    $pics = json_decode($body);
    $ret='';
    if($pics){
       foreach($pics->responseData->results as $pic)
          $ret .= $pic->url.'<br>';
    }
    echo $ret;
?>
```

Comment: `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array on line ...` this is what I get after using your code ;)

Comment: Why -1? i dont know what the api gives you back.

Comment: You would if you would actually access the URL that the OP provided ;)

Comment: just for future reference: `{"responseData": {"results":[{"GsearchResultClass":"GimageSearch","width":"608","height":"766"`...

Comment: now, after your edit, I get a blank response... DO YOU EVEN TEST YOUR CODE?

Comment: it should be `$pic->results[0]->unescapedUrl` OR 2 foreaches OR one foreach but different that what you provided

Comment: No i have not tested it, but i work a lot with curl and jsons... Sorry but the ky was the foreach and if he gets an object he only has to access the unescaped url i think

Comment: Much better :) sorry to be such a pain but I really like PHP when it's done right :)

Comment: I think you two are both excellent. But I still have problem now. I hope you can help me solve it together.

Comment: you have +1 from me for that catch ;)

Comment: I tried the edited code. But it still has something wrong. "Trying to get property of non-object" and "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Comment: Thanks for your patience~ I am not good at coding, but I try to do my best. > <

Comment: By the way, I use Wampserver.  I don't know what to type in "/* Enter the URL of your site here */", and my ip is dynamic.

Comment: Ohhhh... that is the problem. Do you have a registered Domain?

Comment: I still don't how to do. Does it have another way? My target is use it to search images from google and then get the picture link.

Comment: you need a registered Domain

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64878/discussion-on-answer-by-brandelizer-how-to-echo-the-curl-result-in-php).

Answer (score 1):

in order to echo the exact result just use:

```
echo $body; //echoes json string
```

if you want to echo the exact link, echo like this:

```
echo $json->responseData->results[0]->url; //echoes http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20110331075248/peanuts/images/6/62/Snoopy.gif
```

or you can `foreach()` twice (or once...) then `echo $res->url` directly :) your choise!

Comment: I updated my answer with the correct format to output that URL. Please take a look now :) and tell me if you need anything more ;)

Comment: excuse me. when I echo $body, there is nothing to occur.
I also try this code "echo $json->responseData->results[0]->url;"
but happened error "Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: in your case, `$body` should contain the json string. Try to `var_dump()` it and tell me what it outputs ;)

Comment: this could be because your $body does not contain that exact json string... it might be different... just var_dump() it and then tell me what you get ;)

Comment: this means that the cURL request is not valid

Comment: let me just check something ;) I will update my answer

Comment: You have forgotten the CURLOPT_REFERER look at my answer i have edited it