# Curl json results with post variables with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl

I have made a CURL script which post some parameters to my other site to search and show results in JSON with

```
curl "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:9080/crawl.json?spider_name=friendsearch" -d '{"request": {"url":"https://www.example.com/results?name=Robert%20June&citystatezip=Seattle,WA","callback":"parse"},"spider_name": "friendsearch"}'
```

It works well give me JSON array, like

```
{"status": "ok", "items": [{"fullname": ["Robert June"], "current_street": "Address, WA 00000", "previous_addresses": ["Address1", "Address2", "Address3", "Address4", "Address5"], "cellphones": ["(000) 000-0001", "(000) 000-0002"], "landlines": ["(000) 000-0001", "(000) 000-0002"], "emails": ["xxx@xxx.com", "xxx@xxx.com"], "url": "https://www.example.com/results?name=Robert%20June&citystatezip=Seattle%2CWA&rid=0x0"}], "items_dropped": [], "stats": {"crawlera/delay/reset_backoff": 3, "crawlera/request": 3, "crawlera/request/method/GET": 3, "crawlera/response": 3, "crawlera/response/banned": 1, "crawlera/response/error": 1, "crawlera/response/error/banned": 1, "crawlera/response/status/200": 2, "crawlera/response/status/503": 1, "downloader/request_bytes": 1481, "downloader/request_count": 3, "downloader/request_method_count/GET": 3, "downloader/response_bytes": 16123, "downloader/response_count": 3, "downloader/response_status_count/200": 2, "downloader/response_status_count/503": 1, "elapsed_time_seconds": 68.329858, "finish_reason": "finished", "finish_time": "2020-05-06 22:18:18", "item_scraped_count": 1, "log_count/DEBUG": 4, "log_count/INFO": 12, "memusage/max": 59998208, "memusage/startup": 59998208, "request_depth_max": 1, "response_received_count": 2, "retry/count": 1, "retry/reason_count/503 Service Unavailable": 1, "scheduler/dequeued": 3, "scheduler/dequeued/memory": 3, "scheduler/enqueued": 3, "scheduler/enqueued/memory": 3, "start_time": "2020-05-06 22:17:09"}, "spider_name": "friendsearch"}
```

My goal is to call this curl script through PHP and get results on a web page and extract Name, Address, Previous Address, Phone and Landline. I have tried multiple ways with and calling curl like on [How to echo the cURL result in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26910001/how-to-echo-the-curl-result-in-php) but not able to get results and failed.

I have tried with

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx:9080/crawl.json?spider_name=friendsearch');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"request\": {\"url\":\"https://www.example.com/results?name=Robert%20June&citystatezip=Seattle,WA\",\"callback\":\"parse\"},\"spider_name\": \"friendsearch\"}");

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

But it gives

```
array(3) { ["status"]=> string(5) "error" ["message"]=> string(117) "Invalid JSON in POST body. 1:33: Error: Unexpected text after end of JSON value | At line 1, column 33, offset 33" ["code"]=> int(400) }
```

Any idea please?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Can you post what you try in your php script ?

Comment: Thank you. I just edited my question with what I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you need:

```
<?php
    $json = json_decode(shell_exec("curl 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx:9080/crawl.json?spider_name=friendsearch' -d '{\"request\": {\"url\": \"https://www.example.com/results?name=Robert%20June&citystatezip=Seattle,WA\",\"callback\": \"parse\"},\"spider_name\": \"friendsearch\"}'") , true);
    var_dump($json);
?>
```

OR:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx:9080/crawl.json?spider_name=friendsearch');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"request\": {\"url\": \"https://www.example.com/results?name=Robert%20June&citystatezip=Seattle,WA\", \"callback\": \"parse\"}, \"spider_name\": \"friendsearch\"}");

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$json = json_decode($result, true);
var_dump($json);

?>
```

To avoid all this back slashes, you can also change this line to:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"request": {"url": "https://www.example.com/results?name=Robert%20June&citystatezip=Seattle,WA", "callback": "parse"}, "spider_name": "friendsearch"}');
```

How to echo Name, Address etc.:

```
if ($json['status'] === 'ok') {

    $name = $json[items][0]['fullname'][0];                // 'Robert June',
    $currentstreet = $json[items][0]['current_street'];    // 'Address, WA 00000'
    $address1 = $json[items][0]['previous_addresses'][0];  // Address1
    $address2 = $json[items][0]['previous_addresses'][1];  // Address2

    echo "Name: ".$name."<br />\nCurrent Street: ".$currentstreet."<br />\nAddress1: ".$address1."<br />\nAddress2: ".$address2."<br />\n";

// Can also do:

    echo "Name: $name<br />\nCurreny Street: $currentstreet<br />\nAddress1: $address1<br />\nAddress2: $address2<br />\n";

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still gives me "array(3) { ["status"]=> string(5) "error" ["message"]=> string(131) "Invalid JSON in POST body. 1:0: Error: Unknown numeric value keyword: 'cdf7af14bdeb' | At line 1, column 0, offset 0 (AT-START)" ["code"]=> int(400) } "

Comment: @Hashmi you was missing some SPACES, I added them please check.

Comment: Thank you so very much. It worked. Since I am more a Curl person, can you please let me know how can I extract Name, Address, Previous Address, Phone and Landline from the Json result I posted in my question in PHP?

Comment: @Hashmi Most welcome, I added some samples so you get the idea on how to echo Name..

Comment: Thanks so very much. I dont know if its okay to ask or not. can I have paid services of any stackoverflow member to build something for me? I dont want to go through freelancing services because quality is not there. I have tried and a couple developers ruined my projects.

Comment: You are most welcome. I understand it's hard to find a good freelancer. If he is good then he is probably busy with many projects already. Here at stackoverflow you can ask as many questions about programming as you want and its always free and fast. At stackoverflow you can Hire/Offer Job to users here: https://stackoverflow.com/jobs check here how to offer. I will also recommend you to learn programming by use Google and asking questions here, this way you will understand how good your programmer are and you will also be able to continue your project even the programmer leaves you.

Comment: Yeah, I am learning the PHP. Can you guide me with one more thing please? If there are multiple items in the array, how would I echo the details for each one in a loop?

Comment: I had the same issue, check my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31333393/php-how-to-echo-value-from-multidimensional-array